# Android Studio: How to design my own theme?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

So I am running into a problem with my header having the wrong colors. (The header back button and the menu dropdown are both determined by the theme) and I want these to be a custom color.

How would I go about making my own theme, or what else should I do? I can see the Theme Editor is now deprecated, and the one I found online doesn't let me edit what I need to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [theme documentations](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes)

The gist of it is that you can create your own xml theme file and set it as the base theme. You can set all sort of attributes, such as font, colors and element styles.

Here is a blog article which is simpler and more detailed: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidStylesThemes/article.html